# Toggling BottomAppBar visibility not working?

Tags: xaml, prism

I have a list of items - when one is selected, I'd like to slide the appbar up.  This is what I have so far:

```
    <AppBar IsOpen="{Binding BookIsSelected}">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <AppBarButton Icon="Remove" Label="Remove Book" Command="{Binding RemoveBook}" Visibility="{Binding BookIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
```

In the gridview of books, I have this:

```
  SelectedItem ="{Binding SelectedBook, Mode = TwoWay}" />
```

BookIsSelected:

```
    private bool _bookSelected;

    public bool BookIsSelected {
        get {
            return _bookSelected;
        }
        set {
            SetProperty(ref _bookSelected, value);
        }
    }
```

I can see the get/set hit when I select a book, but the appbar never flies out.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where do you fire the `PropertyChanged` event for `BookIsSelected` property ?

Comment: @Amer, I'd imagine that was in the `SetProperty` method... but if not, then you're onto the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any obvious problems with the code that you've shown so far. However, you haven't shown the code for the `SelectedBook` property or `SetProperty` method, so perhaps your problem lies there? Your `SelectedBook` property should look something like this, setting `BookIsSelected` to `true`:

```
private YourDataType _selectedBook;

public YourDataType SelectedBook{
    get {
        return _selectedBook;
    }
    set {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedBook, value);
        BookIsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

However, unless you set the `BookIsSelected` property back to `false` at some stage, this will only work once. Your `SetProperty` method should notify the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of property changes, as @Amer mentioned in the comments. It should look something like this example from the linked page:

```
private void SetProperty([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```